# use of new FormData(form) returns empty object

Tags: javascript, html, form-data

I want to simply get key: values pair in this example.
On my form I have:

```html
<form id="myForm" name="myForm">
     <label for="username">Enter name:</label>
     <input type="text" id="username" name="username">
</form>
```

JS:

```js
var myForm = document.getElementById('myForm');
formData = new FormData(myForm);
```

I get empty object now with:

```
alert(JSON.stringify(formData));
```

Usage of FormData(form) also with Web Workers returns not expected object.

I know that worker cannot access DOM. Form transfered to worker is `{"isTrusted":true}` but with no data.

Comment: I folowed https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData

Comment: I went looking for the wrong direction. Here is what solved problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var myForm = document.getElementById('myForm');
formData = new FormData(myForm);
// formData.append('anotherKey', data); // not like this
var meggedObj = {anotherKey: data}; // constructing new obj.

// add the form key/value pairs
for (var pair of formData.entries()) {
  meggedObj[pair[0]]= pair[1];
}

alert(JSON.stringify(meggedObj));
```